# Why does this crash my roblox game [Lua Script]

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

```lua
waitChid = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("ODMGGame")

_G.player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ODMGGame

_G.Score = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ODMGGame.CanvasGroup.Score

_G.Middle = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ODMGGame.CanvasGroup.Frame.CenterMeasure

while waitChid ~= nil do

if waitChid ~= nil then 

  if _G.Score.Position == _G.Middle.Position then

    if _G.Score.Position >= 3 and _G.Score.Position <= 1 then 

      PressKey("E")

    wait(1)

    print ("Working")

    ReleaseKey("E")

  

      if _G.Score.Position <= 3 and _G.Score.Position >= 1 then 

          PressKey("Q")

    wait(1)

    print ("Working")

    ReleaseKey("Q")

      end

    end

  end

end

end

if waitChid == nil then 

print ("Not A Child Rn")

end
```

I don't know why this crashes my game.

I thought it would auto-time the objects on the screen by evaluating the position and making something happen if it reached it but it does not, it crashes my game.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.